# No sound in XLite softphone calling Asterisk PJSIP channel bound to callcentric

Tags: asterisk, sip, softphone

When calling from an XLite softphone to a Callcentric number which has an Asterisk PJSIP channel registered, we cannot hear anything at all on the softphone (though the call is indeed established).

Note that everything works fine if:

- The call is initiated by Asterisk
- We use Zoiper as a softphone client
- We use chan_sip instead of pjsip in Asterisk
- Asterisk is registered to a different provider, such as nexmo or didlogic

Any ideas?

Comment: No audio is usually a NAT or firewall problem. Check carefully any firewalls or NAT devices in the route.

Comment: @MichaelHampton on the Asterisk or softphone side? Still, the fact that such a precise combination of things triggers the no-sound issue absolutely puzzles me. For instance, if it is indeed a firewall issue, why does it work with other providers, or other softphones?

Comment: That depends on the call direction, and which direction has no audio. If neither direction has audio, you should just check everything end to end.

Comment: Yes, neither direction has audio as you say. The fact that the softphone has no audio could be explained by a router or firewall (though we've checked pretty much everything in the way), but no audio reaching the Asterisk box (which is on a public IP) is strange.